# R "maps" package and choropleths

Tags: r, maps, heatmap

I would like to make a choropleth with the **maps** package in R.  I have data which I have constructed to create bins and associate color names with those bins.  Now, I need to use the col= argument to point the colors to the counties, in this example.  How do I construct that argument?  I would have thought that constructing a data frame would associate the county and color on the same line?  Is that not true? So far I have the following

Example Data:

```
County    |  Value | Bin | Color
alamance  |   100  | 1   | white
brunswick |  1000  | 2   | red
 ... through 100 counties
```

R code (which does not work):

```
library("maps")
DATA <- read.csv("~/Example_Data.csv")
DATA$County <- as.character(DATA$County)
DATA$Color <- as.character(DATA$Color)
NC <- map('county', 'north carolina', col= DATA$Color, Fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the wording in your data set. Please provide an example for your problem and some data of your `*.csv` file.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: The data has been cleaned and standardized to reflect the maps package database which drives the county names.  It is essentially the same as the examples given above.  The error occurs in that the map plot is created, but random colors appear as fill (not those specified by DATA$Color).  I can't determine how to associate the county names and the color fill in the col= element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many iterations here is the essence of the solution.  Instead of giving the R code which made it work (pretty bland), here are the rules that helped solve the problem.

1. The county.fips data included in the package has a column with all states and county names.  This revealed the formatting of county name matches which are all lowercase, "state,county" with no spaces.
2. For the NC subset there are 102 entries, not 100, because Currituck County is subdivided into three entities.  This was the source of most/all of the issues and was difficult to diagnose but easy to solve.

**Solution 1** - Match a vector of colors to the vector of counties.  102 color entries **IN THE PROPER ALPHA ORDER** will produce a correctly resulting choropleth.  Fastest, but also the least convenient if you were trying to do this for, say, all counties in the U.S.

**Solution 2** - Add fips codes to original data and then match on fips.  Since the county.fips file has Currituck entities listed as "north carolina,currituck:main", etc., this is still going to take some manipulation or finding an external fips reference.  This is the method used in the maps() documentation, but which would have taken too long so I preferred the former.  However, taking the time would allow you to approach a national dataset, for instance.